# Set the DbContext for Class that Derives it

Tags: sql-server, entity-framework, dbcontext

So I have a class that derives DbContext. It looks like:

```
public class ATPublicRestContext : DbContext
{
    public ATPublicRestContext dbcontext;

    public ATPublicRestContext() 
    {
        dbcontext = getDBContext();
    }

    public DbContext getDBContext()
    {
        ATPublicClient client = new ATPublicClient();

        //get context from service bus
        DbContext context = client.DBContext().context;
        return context;
    }
}
```

My question is how do I set the context returned in the getDBContext function to the context for ATPublicRestContext?

The context needs to be returned remotely so the above is the closest I've gotten. The line

```
dbcontext = getDBContext();
```

does not work, nor does

```
dbcontext = (ATPublicRestContext)getDBContext();
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks.

Comment: Regarding the `dbContext` field: Why would you do this?? Where does it stop? Context in a context in a context etc...? What is the point of returning a `DbContext` from `getDBContext`? What are you trying to accomplish?

Comment: There are other methods in the ATPublicRestContext class that are needed

Comment: ... But you are using composition of the same type, you already have access to whatever it is you think you need.

Comment: I guess you need to create an Interface and return it in your method getDBContext, because I assume your client..context can be any so how could you parse to ATPublicRestContext

Comment: `how do I set the context returned in the getDBContext function to the context for ATPublicRestContext` ? This question does not make sense. Why not just return `this` as it is being called on that same type? Alternatively just have the caller cast the reference to a `DbContext` if that is really what you want....

Comment: Also `it does not work` does not help anyone. **How** does it not work? Do you have an exception? A build error? Unexpected result? You need to define exactly what does `does not work` means.

Comment: I'll try to explain better. I need an instance of ATPublicRestContext that has it's context equal to what is being returned by client.DBContext().context. The methods I've tried throw type mismatch exceptions

Comment: *get context from service bus* -- I never heard of any `DbContext` instance being transferred over a wire. Is that really what you're trying to achieve?

Comment: Yes it is. I am trying to set an ATPublicRestContext's DBContext equal to a DBContext that is passed in.